# The box API for authenticating user is returning random expiry time after every call

Tags: c#, box-api, boxapiv2

I am using box content API in my application.While I was implementing it,authentication response used to contain 3600 expiry time.But now some times it returns 4225, sometimes 4228.Is this normal behavior or a known glitch.Please, note that I am not providing the "box_access_token_expires_at" parameters during authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. The token expiration is nominally 3600 seconds. Box adds a random bit of extra time to smooth out the load of clients refreshing tokens.